# Creating unit tests for generated PDFs using iText

Tags: java, unit-testing, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

We're using iText to read an input PDF, then add messaging and saving the output.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputFilepath);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(outputFilename, true));
PdfContentByte over = stamper.getOverContent(1);
over.beginText();
over.showTextAligned(align, text, x, y, angle);
...
over.endText();
stamper.close();
```

Is there a way of reading in a PDF generated in a unit test and then checking that the supplied text exists at the correct x, y coordinates?

Comment: You can use any PDF library which allows you to do text extraction with positions in your unit tests. iText itself has a text extraction framework which can easily be adapted to not only return the text but also its position. If you want to not use the same library to test results as is used to originally create them, other libraries will also do.

Comment: Thanks - I was stupidly searching for 'unit testing with iText' instead of 'extracting text from PDFs' Have now found plenty of answers. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, [don't test the platform](http://b-speaking.blogspot.ca/2009/08/integration-tests-are-scam.html) (or, in this case, third party libraries you're using.) Instead, test that you're interacting with it correctly.

In this case, this would imply assuming that `showTextAligned()` will do the right thing, provided that the correct coordinates are passed in. I would then focus on testing that.

This will probably mean that I'd need to hide all the interactions with the PDF classes behind an interface, and that I'd pass a mock of that interface to the calculating code, using it to verify that the correct values were passed for the given sample input.

Answer (score -1):

As a shortcut, you can test the order of text in the PDF in a particular page, using `PdfReader.getPageContent(int pageNumber)`.

This not ideal, but it can be a poor man's positioning test, assuming you print text left to right and top to bottom.

Comment: All of the text that's being added is using X,Y coordinates and I can't guarantee the order in which it's printed. I ended up using a `com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` to pull all of the added text out and then testing to see if each string that I had added was present. Not ideal, but at least testing that all of the messages were present.